# Function Query with parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, function

```
Tax1 = SELECT a.harga_triumph * b.nilai_desimal 
from tbl_detail mc a 
JOIN penyesuaian b on a.id=b.id

Tax2 = Tax1 * (c.nilai_desimal from bea_masuk where kode='BM')

Tax3 = c.nilai_desimal from bea_masuk where kode='PPNImpor' * (Tax1 + Tax2)

Tax4 = c.nilai_desimal from bea_masuk where kode='PPNBM' * (Tax3)

Tax5 = c.nilai_desimal from bea_masuk where kode='PRH' * (Tax3)

AllTax = Tax2 + Tax3 + Tax4 + Tax5

Total Price = a.harga_triumph + All Tax

where a.id=@parameter
```

I am stuck at making this query using function.

English Translation :

```
harga_triumph = unit price
nilai_desimal = decimal (0.1,0.2)
penyesuaian = adjustment
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31244/1

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already solved the problem by not using the function,i just used a simple set on the query which is something like this

```
set @dectax1 = (select round(nilai_desimal,3) from bea_masuk where id=1;
set @tax1 = (select round(harga_triumph * @dectax1)); from tbl_detail_mc where id=1);
```

if you want to display the result,use the query inside @tax1 .
And So on...